# Can non-elevation data be displayed in 3D? Such as EC measurements in soil over a surface?

Tags: 3d-analyst, arcscene, inverse-distance-weighted

I tried creating a tin in ArcScene with a raster I have from an IDW file of salinity at sample points in a field, but I can't get it to display as anything other than flat. My points range from ~1-40 in value. I want to display it in 3D with the highly saline points as high peaks and low saline as depressions. Is this possible?

Comment: What coordinate system are you using in ArcScene?  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscene/the-arcscene-coordinate-system.htm In particular what units is that coordinate system in, and what is the extent of your scene?

Comment: A surface is a surface, though the result might be exceptionally strange.